# Public variables in monobehaviour, do not appear in the Unity editor inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I joined in a project, I wanna add new variables to a script but they do not show up in inspector. Variables do not show up in this specific script but they are appear on another script that I just create and copy them. Both are monobehaviour as shown in the pictures. Both scripts are in same directory.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have some custom editor script to PointOfInterest class? Btw can you post the full code instead of a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I found it, there is a editor scipt, that draw it in inspector.                                                             EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(LoadType);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(imageUrl);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(image);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(audioClip);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(subtitle);

Comment: Debugging questions should include enough information to reproduce the problem. See [mre] for more information.

Comment: Even I could not reproduce it, the reason there was an editor script that I didn't know its  existence which manipulates inspector in unity editor.

Comment: `Both scripts are in same file.` well that is not allowed .. each `MonoBehaviour` **has to** be in an individual script with matching class name!

Comment: And also [Why not upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: "Both scripts are in same file", I mean both of them are in same directory but seperated monobehaviour scipts in this directory. Also no error in console. The problem is clear, one script variables do not serialize on editor but if you create another script and copy exact same values to them works. Because there was an editor script thats manipulate inspector view.(I upload the script in answers that manipulate the other script.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there was an editor script, which can manipulate the inspector view and draw PointOfInterest scipt in a custom way on inspector.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(PointOfInterest))]
public class POI_Inspector : Editor
{

    private SerializedObject soTarget;
    private PointOfInterest p;

    private SerializedProperty experienceType;

    private SerializedProperty video;
    private SerializedProperty videoUrl;
    private SerializedProperty LoadType;

    private SerializedProperty youTubeUrl;
    public SerializedProperty startTime;
    public SerializedProperty endTime;

    private SerializedProperty imageUrl;


    private SerializedProperty subtitle;

    private SerializedProperty backdrop360;
    private SerializedProperty panoAnchorsCount;

    private SerializedProperty experienceName;

    private SerializedProperty latitude, longitude;

    private SerializedProperty regionMap;
    private SerializedProperty regionMapData;

    private SerializedProperty image;
    private SerializedProperty texture;

    private SerializedProperty audioClip;

    private SerializedProperty slides;

    private SerializedProperty emissionMap;
    private SerializedProperty emissionMaps;

    private SerializedProperty panoPrefab;

    private SerializedProperty assetUrlAndroid;
    private SerializedProperty assetUrlIos;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        p = target as PointOfInterest;
        soTarget = new SerializedObject(target);

        experienceType = soTarget.FindProperty("experienceType");

        // Video, Video360
        video = soTarget.FindProperty("video");
        videoUrl = soTarget.FindProperty("videoUrl");
        LoadType = soTarget.FindProperty("videoLoadType");

        youTubeUrl = soTarget.FindProperty("youTubeUrl");
        startTime = soTarget.FindProperty("startTime");
        endTime = soTarget.FindProperty("endTime");

        imageUrl = soTarget.FindProperty("imageUrl");
        subtitle = soTarget.FindProperty("subtitle");

        // Panoguide
        backdrop360 = soTarget.FindProperty("image");
        panoPrefab = soTarget.FindProperty("panoPrefab");


        experienceName = soTarget.FindProperty("experienceName");

        latitude = soTarget.FindProperty("latitude");
        longitude = soTarget.FindProperty("longitude");

        regionMap = soTarget.FindProperty("regionMap");
        regionMapData = soTarget.FindProperty("regionMapData");

        image = soTarget.FindProperty("image");
        texture = soTarget.FindProperty("texture");
        audioClip = soTarget.FindProperty("audioClip");

        slides = soTarget.FindProperty("slides");
        emissionMap = soTarget.FindProperty("emissionMap");
        emissionMaps = soTarget.FindProperty("emissionMaps");

        assetUrlAndroid = soTarget.FindProperty("assetUrlAndroid");
        assetUrlIos = soTarget.FindProperty("assetUrlIos");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        //base.OnInspectorGUI();

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();


        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(experienceType);

        EditorGUILayout.Separator();

        switch (p.experienceType)
        {
            case ExperienceType.VIDEO_360:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(LoadType);
                    switch (p.videoLoadType)
                    {
                        case global::LoadType.locally:
                            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(video);
                            break;

                        case global::LoadType.remotly:
                            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(videoUrl);
                            break;
                    }
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(subtitle);

                    break;
                }
            case ExperienceType.VIDEO_2D:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(LoadType);

                    switch (p.videoLoadType)
                    {
                        case global::LoadType.locally:
                            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(video);
                            break;

                        case global::LoadType.remotly:
                            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(videoUrl);
                            break;
                    }
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(subtitle);

                    EditorGUILayout.Space();
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(emissionMap);
                    break;
                }
            case ExperienceType.PANO_GUIDE:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(LoadType);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(panoPrefab);
                    break;
                }

            case ExperienceType.REGION_MAP:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(LoadType);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(regionMap);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(regionMapData);
                    break;
                }
            case ExperienceType.IMAGE_2D:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(LoadType);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(imageUrl);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(image);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(audioClip);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(subtitle);
                    EditorGUILayout.Space();
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(emissionMap);
                    break;
                }

            case ExperienceType.IMAGE_360:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(LoadType);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(imageUrl);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(image);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(audioClip);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(subtitle);
                    break;
                }
            case ExperienceType.SLIDE_SHOW:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(LoadType);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(slides);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(audioClip);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(subtitle);
                    EditorGUILayout.Space();
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(emissionMap);
                    break;
                }
            case ExperienceType.YOUTUBE:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(youTubeUrl);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(startTime);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(endTime);
                    break;
                }
            case ExperienceType.Asset3D:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(assetUrlAndroid);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(assetUrlIos);
                    break;
                }
            case ExperienceType.AUDIO:
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(audioClip);
                    break;
                }
        }

        if (p.emissionMap)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(emissionMaps);
        }

        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            soTarget.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            GUI.FocusControl(null);
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Your editor should call `soTarget.Update();` at the top of the `OnInspectorGUI` .. only then does `ApplyModifiedProperties` make sense ... `Update` basically loads the current values into the serialized object, `ApplyModifiedProperties` then is the opposite for writing them back

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation. I hadn't come across with any editor code that manipulate script variables in inspector, so I couldn't figure why they are not show up in inspector. After I saw the POI_Inspector script that written by someone else and found the solution.